# Design patterns in React

Tags: reactjs

I need some advice about general design pattern in React.
I have a page that contains table, and there are many other components in this page that use the data from the table. 
My question is in this case what is the best design that recommended?
Currently, I am using one big class that its state handles all this information.
Alternatively, I can lift up the state of this component to Table Wrapper class, but It's seems strange to me that the state of the table will be stored in the wrapper instead of in the table component itself.
Any other advice?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score -1):

From your description it seems like you might benefit from using `[redux][1]` fot your state management.

It works by storing the state data in an outside store that way it is accessible from any point in the application.

Hope this is helpful